# populate jQuery object from an Array

Tags: jquery, arrays

This is my first post and fairly new at jQuery. I'm looking for an elegant solution to populate jQuery object from an Array

I have a dynamic array "carsArray". I like the values from carsArray to be populated into the jquery object. I kinda have something working but I see 2 issues with it.

1. I have hardcoded the carArray to have only 5 values, which is incorrect. It should be flexible.
2. Not elegant coding. I know there is a better way of acheiving the end result.

```
;jQuery(function($) {

    carsArray = ['Nissan','Toyota','BMW'] // this is dynamically build. It could have many more values.

    var carArray = new Array();
    $.each(carsArray, function ( key, value ) {
        carArray[key] = value;
    });

    // '101','102'.. are random indexes. It could be any distinct value.

    $.carspicker.designs['custom'] = {
        '101': [carArray[0]],
        '102': [carArray[1]],
        '103': [carArray[2]],
        '104': [carArray[3]],
        '105': [carArray[4]]
    };

});
```

Really appreciate any advice. Thank you!

Comment: So what you're saying is, you have working code, but you want it to be more better.

Comment: You have `new Array()` -- but are populating that by using a `key/val`..no no no, **objects** are key value pairs, arrays are just index based.

Comment: To be honest I can't tell what the goal of your code is based on the question.

Comment: Not sure I understand... Why do you clone your object? And where do the "random" indexes come from? It is difficult to see what you want to obtain here... I don't see the relation between the random indexes and the carArray indexes.

Comment: Sorry, I omitted some of the details on why I'm doing this as I wanted to keep the post short and relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery(function($) {

```
carsArray = ['Nissan','Toyota','BMW'] // this is dynamically build. It could have many more values.

var carObj= {}; //new object
$.each(carsArray, function ( key, value ) {
    carObj[key] = value;
});

// '101','102'.. are random indexes. It could be any distinct value.

$.carspicker.designs['custom'] = carObj;
```

});
OR

jQuery(function($) {

```
carsArray = ['Nissan','Toyota','BMW'] // this is dynamically build. It could have many more values.

var carArray = new Array();
$.each(carsArray, function ( key, value ) {
    carArray[key] = value;
});

// '101','102'.. are random indexes. It could be any distinct value.

$.carspicker.designs['custom'] = carsObject(carArray);
function carsObject(arr) {
    var maxlength = arr.length,
        i,//this index in array as well as the unique key in the object
        carObj = {};
    for(i = 0; maxlength > i; i += 1) {
        carObj[i] = arr[i];
    }
    return carObj;
}
```

});

Comment: Thank you zubutok. I used the first option and It worked wonderfully!

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you wish to transform an array to an object, and the keys are irrelevent. You could:

```
var cars = ['Nissan','Toyota','BMW'];

var obj = cars.reduce(function(memo, car){
    memo[car] = car;
    return memo;
}, {});
```

but it will work only in EcmaScript 5.

With jQuery, you can use the extend function. I'm not sure it's 100% legal to use an array as argument, but still:

```
var obj = $.extend({}, cars);
```